# How to work WordPress functions and database

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

wordpress experts.
I'm searching some help. I know php as well as javaScript and  ajax. I have worked a few days with wordpress.
But I want to know core functionality of wordpress that means how wordpress functions and database work.

I know about codex. But I am not understanding from where I will start study.
Thanks for regards my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well WordPress is basically just PHP, but with a bunch of functions, classes, methods, and hooks already defined. It works using regular methods to connect to and query a MySQL database. The Codex is the best place to learn about the functions etc.  But you can of course actually look at all the functions in the code to see how they work if you want.

Here is a nice blog post showing Wordpress database structure, but it is a little out of date. http://scotty-t.com/2012/01/30/understanding-mysql-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for providing an useful link.